# vim: how to use a match from a global command in a range following the match

Tags: regex, vim, replace, range, match

In following lines of text, I would like to add the matched text from a global command's search to the range specified after the global command

So to get from this

```
Number 1
  indentA
  indentB
Number 2
  indentC
  indentD
```

to this

```
Number 1
  1 indentA
  1 indentB
Number 2
  2 indentC
  2 indentD
```

I have seen  a similar question and answer not that long ago but I can't find it for the life of me. Following is one of my failed attempts. I understand why it doesn' t work but have no clue how to change it to make it work.

```
:g/\d$/+1,+2s/indent/\=submatch(0).'indent'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

```
:g/\d$/execute '+1,+2s/indent/' . matchstr(getline('.'), '\d$') . ' &'
```

#### Explanation

In your attempt, `submatch()` already refers to the following lines that `:s` processes. The `:g` / `:s` combination has two scopes, you need to grab the number in the scope of `:g`:

```
:g/\d$/echo matchstr(getline('.'), '\d$')
```

Now, we can pass the number into the second stage, the `:s`. One could `:let` a variable, and evaluate that with `:help sub-replace-expr` (as in your attempt), but `:execute` is easier, especially with a number that doesn't require any sort of escaping:

```
:execute '+1,+2s/indent/' . theNumber . ' &'
```

To avoid repeating the search, the `&` comes handy here. `'s/\zeindent/' . theNumber . ' /'` would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your  solution isn't  working because  `submatch()` will  refer to  the `:s`
command and not `:g`. You can use an expression inside your `:s` to grab the
number again, however  this seems a bit repetitive, matching  the number two
times. It could be an easier logic to work on lines with `indent` and search
backwards for a digit:

```
:g/indent/s/\</\=getline(search('\d$', 'b'))[-1:].' '
```

In this command the beginning of the  first word (`\<`) in a line containing
`indent` is  replaced by the last  character (`[-1:]`) of the  previous line
(`'b'`) containing a digit as last character followed with a space (`.' '`).

However, specially if like in your example, there is only one digit per line
so you don't  need to capture the  previous line which ends in  a digit. You
can capture the  digit appearing in the previous  line simply (independently
if it  is a `Number`  or `indent` line. Then,  this wouldn't require  a `:g`
command at all since it is a simple job for regular expressions:

```
:%s/\v(\d).*\n\s+\zs/\1
```

Comment: `\<` was new to me and I had to break down the substitute command to understand why `\zs` was used. Thank you sidyll, it shows there's a lot of ways to skinn a cat. Depressing I wasn't able to find any one of them <g>.

Comment: Thank you @LievenKeersmaekers . I'm sorry, I should have explained better the regex. I'm happy you found your way around it though. Vim regex is very powerful, more than Perl! Often it does solves things by itself (no need for other commands).

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, there are many ways to do it, but don't feel bad about it. Problem solving involves recognizing patterns, and you can only recognize something you know (makes little sense in English, but herkennen / kennen). Although I knew 4 things that you didn't (`\<`, `\>`, `\zs` and `\ze`) you surely know many things which I don't. This exchange of information is what makes it interesting. And now you have these new tools in your knowledge and will already recognize their utility to solve future problems :D

Comment: *you surely know many things...*: mogelijk maar 'k zou er toch niet te veel op verwedden hoor ;).